# Xcode 11: How to stack editor vertically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I like to have 3 Editor windows, 1 Main window and the other half of the screen is split vertically with 2 windows.  I use to be able to do this easily in Xcode 10 and earlier, but looks like I cant in Xcode 11.  Anyone figure this out?

Comment: Do you mean View > Change Editor Orientation ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the assistant view

Answer (score 24):

**Firstly the default behaviour:**

If you click the new window icon at the top right
[image]
then you get a new window to the right of the current one.

**Now for adding a window vertically:**

If you hold down the Alt Key then the icon changes to [image] and then if you click it you will get a new window below the current one.

(Note that if you already have vertically stacked windows the icons default is a vertical split and then pressing Alt reverts it to a horizontal one instead.)

Comment: Omg, life changing moment. Why Apple Team not even made this option inside the menu items, I'm so confused because who will hold down `Opt` to look for things when they are new to Xcode.